# A matrix with positive determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries and $A^{*}$ its conjugate transpose. How can you show that the following $2n \times 2n$ matrix

$\mathbf{X}=\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\mathbf{I}_{n}&{-A}\\
{A^*}&\mathbf{I}_{n}
\end{array}\right]$

has positive determinant?

Any help would be appreciated!

orangeskid

Comment: Are $A^*$ and $A^{\dagger}$ meant to be the same?

Comment: It is [easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) to prove that $|X|=|I||I+A^\star A|=|I+A^\star A|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $T=\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -A^* & I \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $TX = \begin{bmatrix} I & -A \\ 0 & I+A^*A \end{bmatrix}$.

Since $A^*A$ is Hermitian and positive semi-definite, all of its eigenvalues are non-negative, hence the eigenvalues of $I+A^*A$ are all greater than or equal to one, and so $\det (I+A^*A) \ge 1.$

Comment: Oh, so a better statement would be $\det .. \ge 1$. I notice your trick works if we have positive matrices $C$, $D$ on the diagonal, then $\det ... \ge \det(C) \cdot \det (D)$... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One could also use the following theorem (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)):

> [...] if $C$ and $D$ commute (i.e., $CD = DC$), then the following formula comparable to the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix holds:
>
> $$\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(AD - BC).$$

Since the identity matrix commutes with any matrix of the same order, we see that $\det X = \det(I + AA^*)$, which is a determinant of a positive definite matrix, hence it is positive.